# Ruby ternary operator and method call

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.1

I am using ruby 2.1.5, facing some problem with ternary operator

Syntax error

```
request.xhr?  ? render :json => "success"  : redirect_to index_url
```

working

```
request.xhr?  ? render(:json => "success") : redirect_to(index_url)
```

Can some please explain How its works and why above one not working? Thanks in advance

Comment: I may be wrong but I suspect there's an ambiguity for the parser knowing where to split things, adding parentheses remove this ambiguity giving what is a parameter to what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the shorthand syntax (without brackets), ruby expects everything until the end of the line to be parameters to your method. So your "syntax error" example is understood as:

```
request.xhr?  ? render(:json => "success"  : redirect_to index_url)
```

which is obviously wrong.